# Help with "Recent Posts" Loop that is specific to a topic

Tags: recent-posts

I am getting more comfortable with WP but know zero PHP.  I have a site up and running at www.wordpress-temporary.com that I am working on for a client.  It's the twenty-twelve theme with some customization.

What I'm trying to do is make 10 page templates, two for each practice area.

Each practice area has a "home page" which displays a menu specific to the practice area and recent posts of that practice area's topic.  The "internal Page" would add a Google News Feed.  I already made sidebar-biz.php and sidebar-biz-home.php to plug in the to the respective files in the page-templates folder of Business.php and Business-home.php.

I am thinking because there is not any given widget I want on EVERY page was to NOT use the sidebar-1 at all and just plug the items for a given sidebar that I wanted into that sidebar file.  So for example, on my business law home page, I just want that one menu, so my sidebar-biz-home.php (which controls this page: http://wordpress-temporary.com/business-law/) looks like this:

```
> <?php ?>   
> 
> <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary"> <div
> class="menu-wrap">   <h2>Business Law Topics</h2>
>              <?php ubermenu( 'business-subtopics' , array( 'menu' => 23 ) ); ?>      
> 
> 
>  </div>     
>               </div>
```

So what I want, is the line of PHP code to add the recent posts from _____ category to display just under that menu.

So that's really it.  What's the most basic way to include recent posts by plugging coding into the sidebar.php, and what will I need to do to customize it to show only a certain category's posts?

Comment: please read http://wordpressfoundation.org/trademark-policy/

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention.  I will get a different domain name and re-name this site.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your sidebar template where you want the listing to show up. Alternatively, you could use a plugin that allows you to run php in widgets and then place directly in a widget box, but that's not always wise.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$category = $categories[0];
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
$args = array('category__in' => $category_id, 'posts_per_page' => '5');
$recent_in_cat = new WP_Query( $args );if ( $recent_in_cat->have_posts() ) {while ( $recent_in_cat->have_posts() ) {$recent_in_cat->the_post();
?>
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<? php
}} wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Note that the start and end tags `<?php` and `?>` should only be there unless you're already in the middle of (unclosed) php code, else skip them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Again, I have ZERO understanding of PHP.  I'm assuming there is a part of this where I would plug in my specific category name or ID, right?  Do I put that in places of the "cat_ID;" part?    Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @user3299554 it is expected that you at least understand the very basics of PHP, specially syntaxing. You will need this to understand the answers. We are not here to give exact coding solutions, we help you with a basic coding idea which should be enough to help you reach your exact goal. You should really spend your time and learn the basics of php. :-)